# What on earth is CSS3 perspective property?

Tags: css, perspective, css-transforms

I searched online and found several materials, but none of them illustrated this concept clearly, at least for me. For example, the w3schools says it defines how many pixels a 3D element is placed from the view. It's so abstract to totally understand. Can someone tell me in a more vivid easy-to-understand way? It couldn't be better if there are some images to show this concept.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In 3D transformations, perspective gives the object a 3D point of view and attempts to render the perspective of the 3D object from a particular viewer's perspective.  It is not easy to understand.

Here's a [Safari reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/InternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariVisualEffectsProgGuide/Using2Dand3DTransforms/Using2Dand3DTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008032-CH15-SW26) on it.

A [beginning tutorial](http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html) on it.

[Some examples](http://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/) of using perspective.

[Some more examples](http://www.marcofolio.net/css/3d_animation_using_pure_css3.html).

FYI, in the future I'd suggest disregarding all Google search hits that come from w3schools.  They have somehow managed to co-opt a high Google searching ranking with incredibly shallow content.

Answer (score 1):

When working in a **3D** space, we need to set a **perspective** value, otherwise animated elements will look flat. How? The perspective CSS property gives an element a 3D space by affecting the distance between the Z index and the user.Remember: the Perspective property shouldn’t be applied to the element that will be animated (through a CSS Transition, Transformation or Animation), but to a parent element.